# why is there no ad hoc or computer-to-computer option in my windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

i have windows 7 & i want to share my broadband internet connection with my husbands laptop, which has wifi.  i have tried lots of ways to set up the connection.  on my desktop there is no share button under my network.  nor is there a ad hoc or computer to computer option under set up a connection or network.  i don't have bluetooth or wifi on my desktop

Comment: If you have neither Bluetooth nor Wi-Fi, how do you plan to share the connection?

Comment: @waiwai933: I don't believe he grasps the concept of **both** computers needing a wireless card to use a wireless connection.

Answer (score 3):

Ad-Hoc is purely a networking option designed to connect two computers over a wireless connection - it is typically insecure and not advised. If your machine does not have wireless, you will not see this option.

However, most broadband providers give you a wireless router, so if you do have one, you should be able to connect your husbands laptop directly in to that. Try looking at your documentation or the box itself to see if you have a sticker with the connection details (Network name and key).

Alternatively, if you have an older style router with just one connection you may be out of luck. If it is USB, then you can buy a [cross over network cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) (or in some situations, a standard ethernet cable works, so if you have one lying around, try that first) - then simply run the network and sharing wizard, and it should guide you through sharing the connection.

If the router only has one ethernet connection and that is plugged to your PC, you will not be able to do anything as the port is used up.

If the router has more ethernet ports and no wireless, you can plug your husbands laptop straight in to that.

Failing this, your best option with the least hassle is to buy a new wireless ethernet/cable router (e.g. NON modem) this will allow you to plug your current modem/router (if it only has one ethernet out) in to it, then it basically gives you extra ethernet ports and wireless ability.

Lastly, you can buy a USB wireless adapter for your desktop and share over Ad-hoc but I would not recommend this as it lacks security, and your machine has to remain on to share.

I have said a lot here, but if it is confusing at all or you need further help - please write a comment and I will try my best to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a broadband router with wireless built-in or if you already have a router with a multi-port switch, just get a wireless access point. You can then use a wired connection and hubby can use wireless

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Network and internet > Network Connections

Select the two network connections (wired and wireless), right click, chose bridge connections.

This will allow either to connect through the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an Ad Hoc network in W7, go to Networking and sharing Center and click "set up a new connection or network" there will be adhoc options in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Creating an ad-hoc connection, you can connect your phone or any other wireless capable device to your laptop and share internet.

In my case, I was using this connection until last night and today I found out there is no ad hoc connection option in setup new connection. It happened so because I had *disabled the wireless adapter* accidentally. Now that I have enabled it, my connection is working fine.

In case, you have a wireless adapter on your desktop machine, you may want to check if it has been disabled for any reason.

Comment: Looking at the question, I don't think she has a wireless card on her desktop machine. In which case your answer isn't valid at all.